# Entity Framework 6.0 Decoupling Implementing From POCOs

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Lets say I have a couple basic objects and interfaces for them:

```
interface ICar
{
  int Id { get; set; }

  int DriverId { get; set; }

  IDriver Driver { get; set; }
}

class Car: ICar
{
  int Id { get; set; }

  [ForeignKey("Driver")]
  int DriverId { get; set; }

  IDriver Driver { get; set; }
}
```

If I use the implementing class of "Driver" instead of "IDriver" everything is happy (so lets ignore I'm missing additional configuration for all the other values), however using IDriver ends up with the error:

> The property 'Driver' cannot be configured as a navigation property.
>   The property must be a valid entity type and the property should have
>   a non-abstract getter and setter. For collection properties the type
>   must implement ICollection where T is a valid entity type.

So far as I understand it entity doesn't actually support this in any way, my options are:

- Hard couple my POCO interfaces to entity, throwing a wrench into testability and portability, welp.
- Add a transition layer between my POCOs and entity objects (bleh).
- Throw entity out, sort of work around this with some nasty Linq2SQL implementations that sort of support this (though Linq2SQL complains about EntityRefs, it plays fine with EntitySets and interfaces!).
- Find another ORM that will allow me to properly abstract my POCOs from my implementing data provider.

*Or* am I missing something here?

Comment: I understand what you're asking, but I don't understand this bit: "Hard couple my data layer to entity". Entity Framework *is* a data layer. You probably mean you couple the domain to the data layer. Further, I think any ORM causes hard coupling, and the only way to test them well is through integration testing.

Comment: Sorry, meant plain old clr objects, it's late... updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not coupling POCOs to EF, it's the other way around and totally legitimate since domain objects are basic building blocks of your application. Similar to ints, strings, etc...
You would not "interface" int, would you? At any time you throw EF away and take NH, for example, this would not affect your POCOs at all.

Now, custom DbContext and business classes on the other hand ARE the things you need to create  interfaces for. This way you can mock them for test purposes and change implementations.

And one more thing - do not trap yourself with the idea of abstracting EF from the business layer in a self written data access layer. Although, this is achievable, it also puts tons of restrictions on your business layer implementations. You'll have to invent self torturing techniques to write queries which would take 5 seconds of your time otherwise.

In my opinion, the ideal dependency diagram, I came up with after a lot of experiments, now 
looks like this [image]

Domain objects, business and context interfaces are the core of the app. Other layers are independent of each other and therefore testable.

Be mindful thought, that business layer here is dependent on EF and if I ever decide to switch from EF (highly doubt it) I will have to port my business classes. This, I believe, is a very unlikely event and a small price to pay for all the comfort EF gives me in my business classes.

Comment: I guess the biggest issue _is_ that I'm interfacing my POCOs, I gain practically nothing by that if I don't have to attribute my POCOs at all... however I'm having an issue with my implementation of EntityTypeConfiguration<Car> not allowing me to do a 1 to 1 relationship, so far the only way I've achieved that is with the ForeignKey attribute, which is why I'm drifting towards trying to use interfaces in my POCOs again. Additionally I always leaned that way being as that was the only way to abstract your POCOs from Linq2SQL.

Comment: Ok, I guess I resolved the EntityTypeConfiugration problem, I'm going to go ahead and plow our removing interfaces from my POCOs and just going with that and seeing how it goes, thanks!

Comment: In my project I kept the edmx model, disabled models generation TT file and referenced my domain objects assembly. This way pocos don't have any attributes, I don't need to do fluent mapping, and I can still use model designer.

Comment: I modified the context TT file as well to include domain namespaces so it would see pocos.

Answer (score 2):

I've done this a few times. If you want your classes to be entirely separate, free from anything specific to Entity Framework, then you'll have to make a few small changes. Here's what I did:

- Create classes to represent domain entities. I did this in a completely separate assembly (for various reasons) but you don't have to.
- Reference the namespace(s) with your classes in and add sets for them to the `DbContext` as normal.
- Use Entity Framework's Fluent Configuration API to [map your types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617) and [their relationships](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620).

That last part means you may not be able to use attributes like `[ForeignKey]`, as many of them live in `System.Data.Entity` and at that point you're using Entity Framework stuff so you might as well just accept the coupling.

This does mean you'll have to do a little more work to set up the relationships, but it's not too bad, and when you're done your domain classes are entirely separate from Entity Framework, allowing you to mock it for testing or swap it for another ORM pretty painlessly.

Comment: This is right, but still there is coupling, because for EF to function at its best, the "domain" classes should meet a couple of design guidelines. And the class model can't diverge too much from the store model.

Comment: I suppose - although those design guidelines remain relevant in plenty of other ORMs, and generally there aren't too many cases where your store model and domain model are going to be radically different. In terms of "coupling", though, I'm talking in the strict sense, in that the domain classes compile fine without EF, you don't need to know anything about EF to understand them, and you can swap for another ORM without touching anything outside of your data layer. EF might leave some kind of impression on the domain classes, but only in a design sense - not anything the compiler will notice.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to create interfaces for your entities, as you'll end up with header interfaces as you have here, and therefore the interfaces are not abstractions at all and have little value. If you create role interfaces then you can easily stub out the implementations in tests to return the entities you wish.